# Stop Thread in Android App

Tags: android

I Have searched for a few hours on google and on here. I have been unable to find a solution to my problem. I want the thread to stop when the user presses the back button. So for example the user will press the back button and the loop will stop flipping coins. Then the textviews will be populated with the number of heads and tails that the loop managed to complete before the user canceled the operation.

I know i have to set

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

to

```
dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

and that i need to implement

```
progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener(){

  public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

   background.setRunning(false);

  }});
```

But when i try to do this it ends up killing my entire app force closing it.
Can you please help. Im still kind of new to android programming and I am eager to learn more so if you notice any other things in the code i can improve it would be appreciated.

```
package com.michaelpeerman.probability;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class ProbabilityActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button submit;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    int increment;
    Thread background;
    int heads = 0;
    int tails = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        submit = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.submit));
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        increment = 1;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Flipping Coin...");
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        EditText max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
        int maximum = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());
        dialog.setMax(maximum);
        dialog.show();
        background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < dialog.getMax(); j++) {
                    int i = 1 + new Random().nextInt(2);
                    if (i == 1)
                        heads++;
                    if (i == 2)
                        tails++;
                progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    background.start();
}

Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
        if (dialog.getProgress() == dialog.getMax()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
            result.setText("heads : " + heads + "\ntails : " + tails);

        }
    }

};

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm curious how your code compiles, since `setRunning(boolean)` is not part of the api for `Thread`.

Regardless of that, here's one way to exit a thread cleanly. Change your background thread definition to this:

```
background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (int j = 0; !Thread.interrupted() && j < dialog.getMax(); j++) {
            int i = 1 + new Random().nextInt(2);
            if (i == 1)
                heads++;
            if (i == 2)
                tails++;
            progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Then cancel your thread with:

```
background.interrupt();
```

Comment: Thank you. and i dont use setRunning in my code. That part is just something i found that was an example of how to implement a way to kill.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be forcibly closing threads in your app.  This kind of thread management is generally a bad idea and usually completely unnecessary with the kind of niceties provided to you by the Android framework.  Instead what you should be doing is using an AsyncTask that will update the UI (this also eliminates the use of that Messenger, which while in this example is pretty simple, can get much nastier!).  Using an AsyncTask you can perform whatever work you need in the background and update the UI at the same time.. You can read about all of this in the [painless threading Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Answer (score 1):

To stop a thread you should use Thread.interrupt() method, it does not stop the thread immediately, but it notify android system that that particular thread needs to be stopped, and android os interrupts that thread when it is suitable to stop the thread.

Comment: Calling `interrupt()` does not actually cause the system to stop the thread. It just sets the thread's interrupted flag. This will cause the thread to throw an `InterruptedException` if the thread is in a wait state, sleeping, blocked on I/O, or in a couple of other situations. If the thread is not in one of those situations (if it's, e.g., in a compute-bound loop), then it's up to the thread logic to notice that it has been interrupted. See the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Comment: It's still probably pretty questionable to kill a thread like this, at the very least it makes your code dirty.

Comment: it dont makes your code dirty if you use it efficiently, however, there is another option available which makes thread killed itself, when its parent thread is about to kill, by setting thread thread.setDaemon(true);

Comment: @KristopherMicinski How does it make your code dirty? Many people suggest coding up some sort of "please stop" flag in a thread subclass and setting that to signal the thread logic to exit. Using the built-in interrupt status flag instead of an explicitly programmed one is, in my opinion, just as clean and a lot more convenient.

Comment: @jitendrasharma - Setting a thread to be a daemon does not have the effect you describe. The parent thread can exit and the daemon will still run. The main effect is that a Java process will exit when the only threads running are daemon threads.

Comment: I believe it makes your code quite dirty, especially since Android has explicit utilities for this use case.  To use a thread explicitly in this situation when is it is the AsyncTask use case seems to be ignoring an obviously useful API.  While the flag based implementation "works," there are lots of sticky situations you can get into if you don't clean yourself up properly (which is much easier to avoid if you just use AsyncTask to begin with).  So yes, you can do it this way, but I think that would be against the Android way of doing things.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski - `AsyncTask` has some serious flaws. The main problem is that it is very difficult to handle activity restarts due to configuration changes like portrait/landscape flip. (This is not to say that OP's code doesn't have the same problems -- it does (unless OP kills the thread with the activity) -- but just to point out that `AsyncTask` isn't the panacea many people think it is.) See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/vwRrlc84gy0/discussion) for some gory details.

Comment: So your solution is to kill a thread?  I don't see why this would be any different, you still have to handle thread death when your activity is killed and check if the Thread is around maintaining state.  This is still the use case for this API, and I don't see why resorting to a hacky Thread killing implementation could ever be considered a good thing.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski I didn't suggest killing the thread. I suggested calling `interrupt()`. This does _not_ kill the thread; it only sets the interrupted status flag. It is up to the thread to notice and exit in an orderly manner. If the thread is in a state that causes an `InterruptedException` when the interrupted status flag is set, then the thread should be coded to catch that exception and, again, handle it in an orderly manner--exiting, if that's appropriate. There's nothing hacky about this; the interrupted status mechanism was designed exactly for this.

Comment: I didn't mean that you were forcibly killing the thread, but morally this is what you're doing.  I understand that this works, but I don't see why this is any better than using an AsyncTask.  I don't think it's acceptable to say "don't use AsyncTask, it's not good, let's just make up our own solution which does the same thing but also requires using a Messenger for the UI."  I understand this works, but I think using AsyncTask is a better use of the API.  (So, I don't disagree about using this way to kill a thread, just that OP is using a thread in the first place.)