# Cancel android thread programmatically

Tags: android

I have this thread:

```
                    t = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                                Thread.sleep(1);
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        TimeCounter++;
                                        textview.setText("Your reaction time:"
                                                + TimeCounter + "MS");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                };

                t.start();
```

I want to cancel it , I tried the `t.interrupt();` but it didn't work, is there any other way?

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595603/stop-thread-in-android-app

Comment: Thread.sleep(1) is the funniest of all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue related to this before. You might find this link useful as this is how I solved this problem. Also, as already mentioned, it is quite odd that you are setting your thread to sleep for 1 millisecond. 
[Thread isn't removed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185521/thread-isnt-removed-after-it-has-stopped-running)

Comment: I just wanted to update a textview every millisecond so I used thread and sleep for one millisec, is there other way?

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. Personally I would use something like a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). It allows you to specifically state the interval as well.

Comment: This may help you understand how to use it properly in your code.[How to make a countdowntimer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032003/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-android/10032406#10032406)

Comment: I honestly think this would be a better solution than using a thread (although I don't know the exact context of your program). You could have the onTick() handle updating the TextView which would happen based on your interval. Also, I believe that the CountDownTimer runs on it's own type of thread (I could be mistaken).

Comment: You are right but I need it to be for an unknown time so I can't use the CountDownTimer because he might finished, anyway, I solved it, thank you!\

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that it works properly but you have a lot of runonUiThread commands pending.  Doing a runOnUiThread that frequently is NOT recommended, you're doing a lot of processing and inter-thread communication.

Answer (score 0):

Read this :

[How do you kill a thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java)

and :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html